# React Apex Chart, forecast. Display only price of forecast

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

Hello I have a forecast area chart here. Please see the image. I only want the chart to show the forecasted value of "168.23" in blue on the rightmost end of the chart. The rest are not needed.

[image]

here is my code for the chart

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([])

const [series, setSeries] = useState([{
    name: 'Price',
    data: []
}])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${symbol}/${ex}/`, Config())
        .then(response => {
            setSeries([{
                name: 'Price',
                data: [...response.data.prices.map(item => return_strong_num(item)), return_strong_num(response.data.analystRatings.TargetPrice)]
            }])
            setDates([...response.data.dates, response.data.future_date])
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message()))
}, [code, exchange])


const options = {
    chart: {
        width: '100%',
        type: 'area',
        foreColor: graphVar.color,
        toolbar: {
            show: false,
        },
    },
    grid: {
        show: graphVar.grid
    },
    forecastDataPoints: {
        count: 7
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 5,
        curve: 'smooth'
    },
    yaxis: {
        opposite: true
    },
    xaxis: {
        color: graphVar.color,
        type: 'datetime',
        tickAmount: 10,
        categories: dates,
        labels: {
            formatter: function (value, timestamp, opts) {
                return opts.dateFormatter(new Date(timestamp), 'MMM yyyy')
            }
        }
    },
    fill: {
        type: 'gradient',
        gradient: {
            shade: 'dark',
            gradientToColors: ['#FDD835'],
            shadeIntensity: 1,
            type: 'horizontal',
            opacityFrom: 1,
            opacityTo: 1,
            stops: [0, 100, 100, 100]
        },
    },
}

<ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type={'area'}/>
```

So far unfortunately I have found any solution for this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways to show only last label on chart:

First, using css

```
.apexcharts-data-labels{
  display: none; /* Hides all */
}
.apexcharts-data-labels:last-child{
  display: unset; /* Show last */
}
```

Second, changing `formatter` in `dataLabels` [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/#formatter)

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function (val, opt) {
    let data = opt.w.config.series[0].data
    if (opt.dataPointIndex === data.length-1){
      return val; // return value only for last element
    }
    return ''
  }
},
```